# Why do Matlab figures generated in a loop have slightly different file sizes?

Tags: matlab, save, size, matlab-figure, figure

I am performing a parameter sweep. Inside a for loop, the value of a parameter is changed. Based on this parameter, a plot is produced and saved as a `.tiff` file.

I noticed that the resulting files have slightly different file sizes, for instance

> 215, 222, 223, 215, 210, 196, 195, 195, 195, 195 kB.

I wondered why they do not all have exactly the same file size?

**EDIT: MWE**

**1. tiff**

Executing

```
for a=1:3
    b=1:.01:10;
    h=figure(1);
    plot(b,sin(a*b))
    set(h,'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
    filename=horzcat('test_',num2str(a),'.tiff');
    print('-dtiff',filename)
end
```

yields 3 files with resp. file sizes 79, 95, 110kB.

**2. bmp**

Executing

```
for a=1:3
    b=1:.01:10;
    h=figure(1);
    plot(b,sin(a*b))
    set(h,'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
    filename=horzcat('test_',num2str(a),'.bmp');
    print('-dbmp16m',filename)
end
```

yields 3 files with the same file size: 3165kB.

Comment: We need more code that this to say anything useful about this. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Because [tiff might be compressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format#Compression)? Try a bmp. Or can that be compressed too?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Good point, see my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference in file size is to be expected.

In a bitmap image (without compression), the color value of each pixel is stored within a file. It doesn't matter whether all pixels are white, black, or whatever the value of each will be stored. For this reason, all bitmap images (of the same dimension and color depth) are going to be the same size. You are using a 24-bit bitmap meaning that 24-bits are allocated *per pixel* in your figure. [More information on bitmaps](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/bitmaps/).

A TIFF on the other hand is a little more complicated. As @Andras stated, a TIFF can be compressed and the compression *depends on the image contents*. For example, if an image is all black, that is *highly compressible* because it's only one color value for an entire image (results in a smaller file size). If every pixel is a different color this is less compressible (resulting in a larger file size).

In your example, you are changing that data in the plot which changes the distribution of pixel colors in your saved image which is ultimately going to change the file size of a TIFF slightly from iteration to iteration. The only way that you can expect the same file size is if your data is *exactly* the same and the figure is the same size.